# How do I create a sense of Impending Doom?

Tags: cortex-plus, marvel-heroic-roleplaying

I've been reading up on the rules and I've noticed that if the player rolls multiple ones on their action I can choose to either award a PP for each 1 and add a d6 for each opportunity or I can choose to up the step of the dice without awarding additional PP.

How should my thought process work to best achieve a reasonable (but not necessarily overpowering) doom pool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us use *simple* math and probability.

The standard starting doom pool is 2d6. So for starters we get difficulty < 4 66% of the time with d6 effect. That is pretty easy and not really challenging to most heroes.
So what would challenge the heroes? Let's say that a difficulty that they can overcome only 30% of the time is really challenging. How many doom dice would we need for this?

### Boring calculations block start.

Let's assume Captain America as one of our heroes, and try to calculate his average success difficulty. (This is an difficulty that he can best 70% of time without the use of power points.)

- Average affiliation dice (standard for all heroes) is (d6 + d8 + d10) / 3 = d8
- Average distinction dice (which, again, is standard for all heroes) 3d8/3 = d8
- Cap has 2 power sets with average dice [(d12 + d8) / 2] = d10 and 4d8/4 = d8.
- Average specialty dice are [( 4d8 + d10 )] / 5 = 8.4, which is closer to d8.
  *Averaging specialties is a bit tricky because d8 and d10 can be split into smaller dice automatically, so let's assume now that there is no dice splitting involved.*

In the end, Captain America has, for his action, an *average* die pool of 4d8 + d10. (This is completely bogus, but still helps us analyze difficulty.)

Let's assume that the d10 will always go to effect. In 75% of dice rolls total will be 11+, but only 35% will get 13+. Logically, if we want the Captain to fail hard we need our effect at d10 and a total more than 13, or an effect at d12 and total 10 or more. This gives us our "dooming" doom pool expectations.

### Doom Pool Calculation

*Reminder and clarification: **Total** is sum of two dice. Not sum of all.*

So we need at least 1d12 and 1d10 to use as effect dice and a couple of lesser ones to give total of 13 or more.

Total of 13 or more with probability of 0.7 can be achieved with these dice combinations:

- 6d8. Doom pool consists of 1d12, 1d10, 6d8 - 8 dice.
- 5d8 and 4d6. Doom pool consists of 1d12, 1d10, 5d8, 4d6 - 11 dice.

So this is, pretty much, the doom pool that you really need to put good pressure on heroes and, via this, on players. (Moreso from a psychological standpoint: big groups of variable dice in the doom pool are more scary to players because a) there are a bunch of them; b) they are random and undecided, so this means more suspense.)

### Doom Pool Building Strategy

*at last*

1. If you start with 2d6 in pool and heroes have more than 2 pp each, step up your current die.
2. If players actively spend pp - start getting dice in the pool until you have 9. If more than one opportunity arises on the roll, buy a d6 and step up an already existing die.
3. Stepping up higher dice is a more efficient way to build a high difficulty pool. Buying d6s in is a way to build a more consistent difficulty pool.

Also remember that stepping up does not give players pp and can stall the game with a high doom pool difficulty, so when you have a bunch (more than 2) of d12, start interventions -- which speed up the game, give XP to heroes, and drop difficulty at the same time!

Comment: Wow, much better answer than I was expecting this early (my copy came today)

Comment: Sorry but it is like that my probabilities may be of by one die. I will fix it when i gather a little bit more expertise in modelling this roll mechanics.

Comment: sure. Again brand new system (I know various cortex games have been out for a while), my expectations for this are already surpassed :). I look forward to the edit.

Comment: Fixed digits is now in post.

Comment: If you're activating opportunities to step up existing doom dice, don't you have to step up the lowest die in your pool?

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the Doom Pool is best built through introducing Complications early for the PCs to focus on. Rather than pitting them immediately against a villain, allow them to use their efforts to fight smaller independent problems; in "Breakout," for example, I introduced things like "Blackout d10" and "Panicked Crowd d8." This gives them a chance to get warmed up, gaining PP and building the doom pool, before the Act properly begins.